# How to prevent socket-io instantiating two sockets in React / Next.js (currently instantiates on server *and* client)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to get a basic WebSocket setup to work:

- Client: Next.js 14
- Server: Express
- WebSockets: [socket-io](https://socket.io/)

Here's the most important files:

#### Server

My Express server only has a single file that looks like this:

`index.ts`

```
import * as socket from "socket.io";
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new socket.Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: true,
  },
});

io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  console.log(`Connection established`, socket.id);

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected", socket.id);
  });

  socket.on("chat-message", (text) => {
    console.log(text);
    socket.broadcast.emit("chat-message", text);
  });
});

server.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on http://localhost:4000");
});
```

#### Client

On the client, I have two relevant files:

`app/lib/socket.ts`

Here's the problem: This code gets executed twice when the app is first started! I see the `initialize socket` log on the server (i.e. in my Terminal where I run the Next.js app) *and* on the client (i.e. in the Browser console).

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const url = 'http://localhost:4000';
console.log(`initialize socket`); 
export const socket = io(url);
```

`app/page.tsx`

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { socket } from "./lib/socket";

interface Message {
  text: string;
}

export default function Home() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messageHistory, setMessageHistory] = useState<Message[]>([
    {
      text: "hello",
    },
    {
      text: "world",
    },
  ]);

  const newMessageReceived = (e) => {
    console.log(`received message: `, e);
    setMessageHistory((oldMessageHistory) => [...oldMessageHistory, { text: e }]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("chat-message", newMessageReceived);

    return () => {
      console.log(`return from useEffect`);
      socket.off("chat-message", newMessageReceived);
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newMessage = message;
    setMessage("");
    console.log(`sendMessage`, newMessage);
    socket.emit("chat-message", newMessage);
    setMessageHistory((oldMessageHistory) => [...oldMessageHistory, { text: newMessage }]);
  };

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="z-10 max-w-5xl w-full items-center justify-between font-mono text-sm lg:flex">
        <p className="fixed left-0 top-0 flex w-full justify-center border-b border-gray-300 bg-gradient-to-b from-zinc-200 pb-6 pt-8 backdrop-blur-2xl lg:static lg:w-auto  lg:rounded-xl lg:border lg:bg-gray-200 lg:p-4 lg:dark:bg-zinc-800/30">
          <code className="font-mono font-bold">CoolChat </code>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="">
        {messageHistory.map((message, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{message.text}</div>;
        })}
      </div>

      <form
        id="text-input-container"
        className="bg-gray-300 py-4 px-2 w-full flex items-center justify-center"
        onSubmit={sendMessage}
      >
        <div className="text-center bg-white w-full md:w-1/3 px-3 py-2 flex gap-3 rounded-xl drop-shadow-2xl">
          <input
            name="message"
            value={message}
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            id="message"
            className="focus:outline-none px-2 flex-1 rounded-xl"
            type="text"
            placeholder="What do you want to say?"
          />
          <button type="submit" className="rounded-xl px-3 py-2 bg-gray-600 text-gray-100 text-sm">
            Send
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Here's what happens when I run the code:

1. start server with `npm run dev`
2. server prints `Server running on http://localhost:4000`
3. start client with `npm run dev`
4. open new browser window and go to `localhost:3000`
5. client (terminal) prints: `initialize socket`
6. client (browser) prints: `initialize socket`
7. server prints `Connection established wQGEI_1USi_4T9n-AAAB`
8. server prints `Connection established 1SPz0765uUEvMQgBAAAD`
9. (sometimes a third time): server prints `Connection established BOAeHMUMeJ5zb2EJAAAF`
10. open a second browser window and go to `localhost:3000`
11. client (browser) prints: `initialize socket`
12. server prints `Connection established um8qdP-yV9btkqVAAAAH`
13. open a third browser window and go to `localhost:3000`
14. client (browser) prints: `initialize socket`
15. server prints `Connection established um8qdP-yV9btkqVAAAAH`

So, as you see, the first time I connect to `localhost:3000`, the socket gets initialized twice — once the server and once the client.

All subsequent times, with new browser windows navigating to `localhost:3000`, the socket only initializes once (in the browser, not at all on the server) as I would expect.

- Can someone explain why the code is being executed twice, once on the once the client (where I expect it to happen) and once on the server (where I don't want it to happen)? This is probably obvious but I'm a Next.js noob so I'd be grateful for any explanations (and maybe links to some additional resources).
- Can someone explain how to prevent this and only run the code on the client to prevent the "double-connection"?

Comment: You can check if code is being run on server just by checking `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { /* Client-only code */}`

Comment: It doesn't seem that your client code is being run *twice* on server. It executed once on server (while Next.js is doing SSR) and second time in browser. As to why it happens only first time, I think it might be something related to browser caching webpage

Comment: "_It doesn't seem that your client code is being run twice on server._"

Ah sorry, you're totally right. I mistyped that in the final question and now corrected it, thanks for catching that! I meant of course that it's once executed on the server and once on the client. Though, the server-side executes the code only the very first time a browsers connects to `localhost:3000`, not later any more.

Comment: Your react component re-rendered, is what I'm getting from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using Next.js 14 and facing this issue in your local environment. It's likely that React is rendering your component twice which leads to multiple connections being established.

I would recommend you to disable `reactStrictMode` in the `next.config.js` file. It should fix the issue for you.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
}
```